# Send a variable from HtmlService to a Google Apps Script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script function called `showModalReport()` to which I pass an object called `reportData`, which is of the type Javascript object (it has property and value pairs). This function creates and serves an HtmlTemplate:

```js
function showModalReport(reportData) {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('modalReport');

  template.reportData = reportData; // this makes reportData available in the HTML modal dialogue

  template = template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template, 'Test Report');

}
```

Then here's my modalReport.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

Report Name: <?= reportData.name ?>

<input type="button" value="Email Report" onclick="onClickFunctions(???)" />

<script>

function onClickFunctions(reportData) {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( function() { google.script.host.close(); }).emailReport(reportData);

}

</script>
```

The dialogue works and correctly displays the report name, so I know that the `reportData` variable is available. Next I want it so that when the user clicks the button, it calls the `emailReport()` function, which emails the report data to someone then closes the modal dialogue.

Here is `emailReport()`:

```js
function emailReport(reportData) {

  Logger.log('reportData: ' + reportData);

  // the email code

}
```

But the `emailReport()` function needs to have the `reportData` object passed as an argument, and this is the part I'm stuck on. How do I pass `reportData` to `emailReport()`?

I tried these already:

```js
onclick="onClickFunctions(reportData)" // the Javascript console outputs the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: reportData is not defined"

onclick="onClickFunctions(<? reportData ?>)" // reportData gets sent in to the function but is null 

onclick="onClickFunctions(this.reportData)" // reportData gets sent in to the function but is null
```

Any idea how I can send that variable to the function?

Also, I am aware that there are many other questions here that are similar to mine. I read and tried code from many of them, as well as trying what was recommended in Google's HTMLService documentation, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could JSON.stringify reportData and pass that around:

```
template.reportData = reportData;
template.reportDataJSON = JSON.stringify(reportData);
```

then:

```
onclick="onClickFunctions('<?= reportDataJSON ?>');
```

and:

```
function emailReport(reportData) {
    var reportData = JSON.parse(reportData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, for anyone else who might come across this: Cameron's JSON parsing suggestion is a working solution. The first suggestion of using the Force-printing scriptlet syntax of `<?!= ... ?>` produced the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`